# in a select statement in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, select

How to use if and onlf if in a select statement in sql server 2005?

Here is my select statement `select Mat_Id,MeasurementId from InTime`...

Now i want to show `measurementName` which is `Measurment` Table based on `MeasurementId`..

Mind you `MeasurementId` is not a foriegn key...

How to make join with `Measurement` table if there is value in `MeasurementId` field of `InTime` Table

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e42f0234d8.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e42f0234d8.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a left join:

```
SELECT InTime.Mat_Id, InTime.MeasurementId, Measurment.measurementName
FROM InTime
LEFT JOIN Measurment
ON InTime.MeasurementId = Measurment.MeasurementId
```

If you only want the rows that have measurement names, use an INNER JOIN instead of a LEFT JOIN.

Also, you have a typo: Measurment should be Measurement. I'm not sure if that's a problem with your database or your question.